# Number of written records in spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to get a number of read and written records in in structured streaming. I'm using `SparkListener.onTaskEnd()` to capture input and output metrics but it seems that number of written records (`taskEnd.taskMetrics().outputMetrics().recordsWritten()`) is zero however it's not true.

Here is my stream construction:

```java
StreamingQuery writeStream = session
        .readStream()
        .schema(RecordSchema.fromClass(IntegTestRecord.class))
        .option(OPTION_KEY_DELIMITER, OPTION_VALUE_DELIMITER_TAB)
        .option(OPTION_KEY_QUOTE, OPTION_VALUE_QUOTATION_OFF)
        .csv(inputFolder.getRoot().toPath().toString())
        .as(Encoders.bean(IntegTestRecord.class))
        .flatMap(
            ((FlatMapFunction<IntegTestRecord, IntegTestVendingRecord>) (u) -> {
                List<IntegTestVendingRecord> resultIterable = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    IntegTestVendingRecord result = transformer.convert(u);
                    resultIterable.add(result);
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    System.err.println("Ooops");
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }

                return resultIterable.iterator();
            }),
            Encoders.bean(IntegTestVendingRecord.class))
        .writeStream()
        .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
        .format("parquet")
        .option("path", outputFolder.getRoot().toPath().toString())
        .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointFolder.getRoot().toPath().toString())
        .start();

    writeStream.processAllAvailable();
    writeStream.stop();
```

Tested it with one good and one bad (unparsable) input records and here is output:

```
(TestMain.java:onTaskEnd(75)) - -----------recordsWritten--> 0
(TestMain.java:onTaskEnd(76)) - -----------recordsRead-----> 2
(TestMain.java:onTaskEnd(83)) - taskEnd.taskInfo().accumulables():
(TestMain.java:onTaskEnd(84)) - duration total (min, med, max) = 323
(TestMain.java:onTaskEnd(84)) - number of output rows = 2
(TestMain.java:onTaskEnd(84)) - duration total (min, med, max) = 364
(TestMain.java:onTaskEnd(84)) - internal.metrics.input.recordsRead = 2
(TestMain.java:onTaskEnd(84)) - internal.metrics.input.bytesRead = 157
(TestMain.java:onTaskEnd(84)) - internal.metrics.resultSerializationTime = 3
(TestMain.java:onTaskEnd(84)) - internal.metrics.resultSize = 2396
(TestMain.java:onTaskEnd(84)) - internal.metrics.executorCpuTime = 633807000
(TestMain.java:onTaskEnd(84)) - internal.metrics.executorRunTime = 683
(TestMain.java:onTaskEnd(84)) - internal.metrics.executorDeserializeCpuTime = 55662000
(TestMain.java:onTaskEnd(84)) - internal.metrics.executorDeserializeTime = 58
(TestMain.java:onTaskEnd(89)) - input records = 2

Streaming query made progress: {
  "id" : "1231f9cb-b2e8-4d10-804d-73d7826c1cb5",
  "runId" : "bd23b60c-93f9-4e17-b3bc-55403edce4e7",
  "name" : null,
  "timestamp" : "2018-01-26T14:44:05.362Z",
  "numInputRows" : 2,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.8163265306122448,
  "durationMs" : {
    "addBatch" : 1994,
    "getBatch" : 126,
    "getOffset" : 52,
    "queryPlanning" : 220,
    "triggerExecution" : 2450,
    "walCommit" : 41
  },
  "stateOperators" : [ ],
  "sources" : [ {
    "description" : "FileStreamSource[file:/var/folders/4w/zks_kfls2s3glmrj3f725p7hllyb5_/T/junit3661035412295337071]",
    "startOffset" : null,
    "endOffset" : {
      "logOffset" : 0
    },
    "numInputRows" : 2,
    "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.8163265306122448
  } ],
  "sink" : {
    "description" : "FileSink[/var/folders/4w/zks_kfls2s3glmrj3f725p7hllyb5_/T/junit3785605384928624065]"
  }
}
```

The number of inputs is correct but the number of written records taken from `taskEnd.taskMetrics().outputMetrics().recordsWritten()` is zero.
Even accumulables don't have a correct value - should be 1 but it shows 2 'number of output rows'

Is it a bug? Or my stream is not constructed correctly? Is there any reliable way to count number of read and written records?

#### Update

Opened issue with Spark regarding number of written records: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23288